# Python Library for installation of Graph tool

Tags: python, boost, graph-tool

In order to install Graph-tool, I have first installed pythons 3.2 and C++ boost library boost_1_56_0. However when I run ./configure for graph tool. I got the following error:

checking for boostlib >= 1.53.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::Python library is available... ./configure: line 17408: test: too many arguments
yes
checking for exit in -lboost_python... no
checking for exit in -lboost_python... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_python... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_python... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_python... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_python... (cached) no
configure: error: No usable boost::python found

My boost installation is under= /var/boost_1_56_0

boost library=                  /var/myboost

GraphTool=                     /mnt/data/home/foo/graphtool/graph-tool-2.2.35

Python=                       /mnt/data/home/foo/graphtool/Python-3.2.6

Can you please help me How can I fix this issue.

Comment: If you are on linux, you can simply use pre-compiled binaries.

Comment: @Peaceful provide more detail, I've been struggling with issue as above.

Comment: Have a look at https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#gnulinux